# UART Error at 115200 baud rate, PIC with ESP32

Tags: c, pic, esp32

im trying to communicate a PIC 16F887 with and ESP32 moudule, im trying to send some numbers just to test the UART communication but, reading the ESP32 reception (im reading at arduino monitor serial) its giving me incorrect values, for example, im sending a 1 on the pic and the ESP32 receive a 6, sendig a 8, sendig a 3, and receiving a 14. I dont know if this error code is related to de SPBRGH register, but I need help.

Here is my code of the PIC at C:

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "MPU6050.h"
#include "I2C.h"
#include "USART.h"



//Definimos variables
char Ax, Ay, Az;
uint8_t contador;
uint8_t valorRX;


// BEGIN CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = INTRC_NOCLKOUT  // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3 is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)
//END CONFIG




//Prototipos de funciones
void setup(void);
void __interrupt() isr(void);



//Configuramos interrupciones
//Interrupciones

void __interrupt() isr(void) {
    if (PIR1bits.RCIF == 1) {
        valorRX = UART_get_char(); //Aqui recibimos el dato de la recepcion
        PIR1bits.RCIF = 0;
        //   PORTD = valorRX;
    }
}

void main() {
    setup();
    MPU6050_init();
    UART_config();
    while (1) {
        UART_send_char(0);
        UART_send_char(1);
        UART_send_char(2);
        UART_send_char(3);
        UART_send_char(4);
        UART_send_char(5);
        UART_send_char(6);
        UART_send_char(7);
        UART_send_char(8);
        UART_send_char(9);

void setup(void) {
    ANSEL = 0;
    ANSELH = 0;
    TRISA = 0;
    TRISA = 0;
    PORTA = 0;
    TRISB = 0;
    PORTB = 0;
    TRISC = 0;
    PORTC = 0;
    TRISD = 0;
    PORTD = 0;
    TRISE = 0;
    PORTE = 0;
    contador = 0;
    I2C_Master_Init(100000);
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1; //Habilitamos las interrupciones
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; //Habilitamos las interrupciones perifericas
    PIR1bits.RCIF = 0; //Apagamos la bandera del RX
}
```

And my librarie of UART is:

```
#include "USART.h"

void UART_config() {


    //Para la TRANSMISION
    TXSTAbits.TXEN = 1; //Habilitamos la transmision - La bandera TXIF se pone 1 auto.
    TXSTAbits.SYNC = 0; //Configura EUSART para operacion asincrona
    RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1; //Habilita el EUSART Y PONE TX/CK I/O pin como salida
    TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 0; //Lo ponemos como salida para asegurar
    TXSTAbits.TX9 = 0; // No usaremos los 9 bits solo 8

    //Para la RECEPCION

    RCSTAbits.CREN = 1; // Habilitamos la recepcion
    PIE1bits.RCIE=1; //Se habilita la interrupcion de la recepcion
    RCSTAbits.RX9 = 0; // No usaremos los 9 bits, solo 8
    TRISCbits.TRISC7 = 1; //Lo ponemos como entrada para asegurar

    //BAUD RATE
    SPBRG = ((_XTAL_FREQ/(8*Baud_rate))-1)/2;
    TXSTAbits.BRGH = 1;


}

void UART_send_char(char bt) {
    while (!TXIF); // ESPERAMOS HASTA QUE ESTE LIBRE LA BANDERA
    TXREG = bt; //YA QUE ESTA LIBRE CARGAMOS EL DATO
}

void UART_send_string(char* st_pt) {
    while (*st_pt) //SI HAY ALGUN CHAR
        UART_send_char(*st_pt++); //Lo procesamos como un dato
}

char UART_get_char() {
    if (RCSTAbits.OERR==1) //Vemos si hay error
    {
        RCSTAbits.CREN = 0; //Si lo hay reseteamos la recepcion
        RCSTAbits.CREN = 1; 
    }

    while (!PIR1bits.RCIF); // esperamos hasta que la bandera este libre
    return RCREG; //amos el dato de retorno


}
```

I will ve very grateful, if someone can help me.

Comment: What's the code on ESP32 side?

Comment: And exactly how are they wired together?

Answer (score 1):

Your baud rate formula is wrong.

```
//BAUD RATE
SPBRG = ((_XTAL_FREQ/(8*Baud_rate))-1)/2;
TXSTAbits.BRGH = 1;
```

From table 12-3, page 160 pf the datasheet:

```
// Assuming: 
#define BAUD_RATE 115200ul

TXSTAbits.BRGH = 1;
SPBRG = ((XTAL_FREQ / BAUD_RATE) / 64) - 1;
```

Yet, this does not ensure a perfect 115200 baud rate.  The actual baud rate will be, using the formula in eample 12-1:

```
unsigned long actual_baud_rate = XTAL_FREQ / (64 * (SPBRG + 1));

long delta  = actual_baud_rate - BAUD_RATE;
float error = (float)delta / (float)BAUD_RATE;
```

If this error is over +-4%, serial comms will not be possible at that speed, and you'll need to select another main oscillator, see table 12-5 of the datasheet.  Alternatively, you can try and find a matching non-standard baud rate to communicate with the Arduino.  In that case, you will need to fudge the Arduino port speed as well, similar restrictions apply for the Arduino as well.